# Function for reading bits

Tags: c, bitwise

I've made this simple function for reading **N** bits from an `unsigned char*`  (with a possible offset) and I'm willing to share it here, get a review, suggestions for improving it, etc...

```
typedef struct bits_t {
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int len;
} bits_t;

bits_t *read_bits(unsigned char *src, int bits_offset, int nbits){

    unsigned int curr_bit, curr_byte, remaining_to_read, bit_position_in_byte;

    curr_bit = curr_byte = 0;
    remaining_to_read = nbits;

    bits_t *bits = malloc(sizeof(bits_t));

    bits->len = nbits;
    bits->data = calloc(1, bits->len);

    for(curr_bit = 1; curr_bit <= nbits; curr_bit++){
        if(curr_bit >= bits_offset && remaining_to_read){
            curr_byte = (curr_bit - 1) / 8;
            bit_position_in_byte = (curr_bit - 1) - (curr_byte * 8);
            bits->data[remaining_to_read - 1] = read_bit(src[curr_byte], bit_position_in_byte);
            remaining_to_read--;
        }
    }

    return bits;
}
```

Main:

```
unsigned char *x = "oo";
bits_t *bits = read_bits(x, 0, 16);
for(i = 0; i < bits->len; i++){
    printf("%d", bits->data[i]);
}
```

Result: `0110111101101111`

Comment: 1.  Your function is never called.  2.  Have a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863499/conversion-of-char-to-binary-in-c) (or other similar questions) and note that your code could be made much shorter and faster.

Comment: 1. I'm just showing how I'm calling my function. Obviously, I'm doing that inside main... 2. Err... Do you even know what my function is doing?

Comment: 1.  A full working example would be appreciated.  Show main. Your code shows x is assigned, never used, and then a result is printed.  2.  There are library functions to produce binary representations of char/int.  Why wouldn't you use them?

Comment: 1. Done, sorry for the confusion. 2. Because I'm not reading entire bytes.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it would be more efficient if you determined the input chars to iterate over and then placed the appropriate values (mostly one input byte at a time) into your struct.  This should reduce the index calculations

Comment: I would much rather pass in a `bit_t *` than allocate one inside the function and pray the caller will remember to free it later.

Comment: Your `read_bit` implementation seems to be missing. Is it a macro or an actual function?

Comment: Use `size_t` rather than `unsigned int` for `len` and `nbits`.  Maybe also `bits_offset`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Consider checking `src[currentByte]` for `'\0'` and abort when it's true (apparently the passed in string wasn't long enough). Depends on your usage though.
2. Alternatively to the previous point you could add a `source_length` parameter to let the caller supply the information of how long the sequence really is.
3. I would consider changing the interface slightly. Have some methods which manage the object for you:

   ```
   bits_t *new_bits_t(int nbits)
   {
        bits_t *res = malloc(sizeof(bits_t));
        res->data = calloc(nbits);
        res->len = nbits;
        return res;
   }

   // frees the memory allocated for the structure and sets the reference to NULL
   void delete_bits_t(bits_t **bits)
   {
        if (bits == NULL || *bits == NULL) return;
        free((*bits)->data);
        free(*bits);
        *bits = NULL;
   }
   ```

   Then your `read_bits` function could fill in the  structure passed in and also return error code in case the reading failed (i.e. source is too short):

   ```
   int read_bits(unsigned char *src, bits_t *bits, int bits_offset)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. `bit_position_in_byte = (curr_bit - 1) - (curr_byte * 8);` should be equivalent to `bit_position_in_byte = (curr_bit - 1) % 8;`
5. Your loop is one based for some reason but inside the loop you have to subtract 1 from `current_bit` everywhere. You should just make your loop 0 based which would de-clutter the loop a bit.
6. I would find `bit_in_byte` just as descriptive a name as `bit_position_in_byte`.
7. You could get rid of the `remaining_to_read` by calculating the position:

   ```
   for (curr_bit = 0; curr_bit < nbits; ++curr_bit) {
       input_bit = curr_bit + bits_offset - 1;
       input_byte = input_bit / 8;
       bit_in_byte = input_bit % 8;
       bits->data[nbits - curr_bit - 1] = read_bit(src[input_byte], bit_in_byte);
   }
   ```
8. The loop apparently fills `data` from the end which seems little bit unexpected to me (kind of string reversal).

Comment: Let me get home and apply those changes :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `_t` as a suffix is [reserved by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225396/1157100).  Also the structure is
unnecessary.  The `len` field is essentially unused - the caller knows the
length already.  So just allocate and return an array.  Note that you need to
check that the allocation succeeded.

Parameter `src` should be `const`

Why is everything unsigned except `nbits`?  I would make all apart from the chars signed -
making things unsigned adds nothing here and so is just 'noise'.

Variables should generally be defined one per line and initialised immediately
- although it is better to define them at the point of first use.

It is normal to start indexing at 0 rather than 1.  And your loop should start
at `bits_offset`, rather than starting at 1 and indexing through.

Here is a revised version. Note the use of `%` to get the bit offset.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned char* read_bits(const unsigned char *src, int offset, int nbits)
{
    unsigned char *s = malloc((size_t) nbits);
    if (s) {
        --nbits;
        for (int bit = offset; nbits >= 0; ++bit, --nbits){
            int byte = bit / 8;
            int bit_position = bit % 8;
            s[nbits] = (src[byte] >> bit_position) & 1;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Good, but I think you've misinterpreted the function's intent, which is to interpret arbitrary data as numeric bits.  I think `unsigned char *bits_big_endian(const char *src, int bit_offset, unsigned int nbits)` would be a more appropriate signature. Data, being non-numeric, are most naturally `char[]`, not `unsigned char[]`. @alexandernst wants the output as `0` and `1`, not `'0'` and `'1'`. A numeric bit would be `unsigned char`, and a numeric bit string should not be terminated with `'\0'`.

Comment: @200_success thanks, you are quite right. I modified it to fit the spec.

Comment: Sorry for not replying yesterday, I was busy. I tried your code but it won't return anything actually. Have a look here: http://ideone.com/v1BJCV

Comment: Alex, the code you tried was the edited version above but with my original `main` (which assumed a string was returned).  I removed `main` from the code above because your original `main` works with this code.  My original code, which output a string can be seen if you click on the "edited 21 hours ago" link below the code.